# Is it normal when my dialogflow training page is filled with GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME?

Tags: dialogflow-es

My training page is filled with GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME for every row. Is this normal? The agent works fine actually, just the training page is hard discern with every rows having the same name.

Sorry can't post image yet, so only can provide links to the screenshot

1. Page fill with GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME screenshot
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhhVa.jpg
2. GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME with no intent invoked screenshot
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQV3L.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is normal in the training tab in Dialogflow. It depend on how your app is invoked.